# unite doesn't keep factors

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

`unite` of tidyr should create a factor if two factor columns are merged.

I like the tidyverse and I like tidyr.

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- data.frame(col1=c("a","b","a","b","c"),col2=c("x","x","y","y","y"))
d %>% str
e <- d %>% unite("new",col1,col2)
e %>% str
```

I wanted the `new` column to be a factor. The levels should be ordered according to the consisting factors `col1` and `col2`.

Any idea, if I am just using tidyr wrong? Or should I ask the developers to include that as a new feature possibly?

Edit: Maybe this question is more discussion than a real question..

Comment: The levels cannot be ordered according to the consisting factors because you create new factors: `a_x`, `b_x` etc did not exist before.

Comment: 1. unite doesn't even create a new factor, because the column new is a character column.


2. Also, there would be a canonical ordering, right? if a<b<c and x<y, then a_x<a_y<b_x<b_y<c_x,c_y I think that is called "lexicographic order": Sorting based on the sorting of the components and their order in the word.

Comment: `unite` does not create factors but pastes columns into a new columns.
Factors cannot directly be pasted into new factors because factors are integers.
Try for example `f1 <- factor("a"); f2 <- factor("x"); c(f1, f2); paste(f1, f2, sep = "_")`.
`unite`works like `paste`: the inputs are converted to character and then concatenated.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. I meant, after concatentating, `unite` could change the type of the resulting column to a factor, or are there some arguments against that functionality? Or is unite supposed to return a column of type character?

Comment: @TobiasHofmann `unite` returns a `character` column; one of the key features of `tidyverse` functionality is that columns of class `character` will *never* be converted into `factor`s. I consider this one of `tidyverse`s strengths, as numerous mistakes in base R data manipulation can be traced to issues with understanding the difference between `factor`s vs. `character` vectors, and/or automatic conversions between the two types. So if you want `factor`s you need to manually convert the `character` column into a column of `factor`s.

Comment: [continued] From Hadley's [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/factors.html): *"Historically, factors were much easier to work with than characters. As a result, many of the functions in base R automatically convert characters to factors. This means that factors often crop up in places where they’re not actually helpful. Fortunately, you don’t need to worry about that in the tidyverse, and can focus on situations where factors are genuinely useful."*

Comment: Ah, very good. Thanks for the clarification. Even if I don't agree with it, now I know why it is implemented that way and that it won't change. It's a shame though; as a mathematician, I interpret uniting factor columns as the cartesian product of the variables.